# How to hide/show JQGrid inline navigation button from javascript

Tags: jqgrid

[image]
Hide and show Add and Cancel button programmatically in JQGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make Add and Cancel button hidden of visible in the same way like any other elements on the HTML page. You can use `jQuery.show`, `jQuery.hide` or `jQuery.css` with `"display", "none"` or `"display", ""` parameters. Thus the only thing which you need is to get DOM elements which represent the buttons. You can get the elements by `id` for example.

jqGrid assigns ids to all standard buttons. The ids of buttons added by `inlineNav` will be build from grid id as prefix and strings `"_iladd"` (for Add button), `"_iledit"` (for Edit button), `"_ilsave"` (for Save button) and `"_ilcancel"` (for Cancel button). So if you have the grid with id="mygrid" then `$("#mygrid_iladd").hide()` can be used to hide the Add button and `$("#mygrid_ilcancel").hide()` to hide the Cancel button. To hide both buttons you can use `$("#mygrid_iladd,#mygrid_ilcancel").hide()`.

Comment: This is the  way i did and it's working fine :                                                                             $("#" + CityMaster.idGrid + "_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
 $("#" + CityMaster.idGrid + "_iladd").addClass('ui-state-disabled');

Comment: @shyamshankar: You asked to hide/show the buttons in your question and not enabling/disabling. You don't wrote which version of jqGrid and which fork you use. jqGrid which I use don't set `ui-state-disabled` automatically.